# What is the difference between "ato ichinen" and "ichinen go"?

Tags: grammar

Both mean "after 1 year" right? Are they the same or a bit different in usage? When do you use "go" and "ato"? Example : "ato ichinen shitara Nihon ni iku" and "ichijikan go ni iku". Are they interchangable?

Comment: This question needs examples. I guess there are specific cases where indeed they could be translated as "after 1 year", but possibilities are quite vast here and it's risky to claim they both mean the same. "One more year", "one year to go", "one year after", "the next year"... in such examples they cannot be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They might be confusing, but:

- 一年後 いちねんご *ichinen go* — one year after(wards); one year later
- 一年後 いちねんあと *ichinen ato* — one year later; one year behind
- 後一年 あといちねん *ato ichinen* — one year remaining; one year to go (until)

(The word あと is written in hiragana more often than not.)

So, there are significant differences between them, though I don't deny they could be used interchangeably in some situations.